# How to get the anchor href from getSelection() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented a rich text editor with create links function. I can create links but when I want to update a link, for example, I click on an existing anchor node and click on the 'Link' button, it doesn't show the original url. How can I make it show the original url? So far, this is what I have:

```js
$.fn.createRichTextEditor = function(width, height = "auto") {
  var iframeDocument;

  var iframeDocumentId = this.attr("id") + "-rte-editor";

  var newHtml = "<div id='rte-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte'>" +
    "<ul class='rte-toolbar'>" +
    "<li id='createLink'><button id='rte-createLinkBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button-link' value='createLink' title='Link'>Create Link</button></li>" +
    "</ul>" +
    '<div id="' + iframeDocumentId + '-container"></div>' +
    "</div>";

  this.after(newHtml);
  this.css('display', 'none');

  var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
    id: iframeDocumentId,
    class: 'rte-iframe',
    style: 'width;100%;height:' + height,
    load: function() {
      iframeDocument = this.contentDocument;
      iframeDocument.designMode = 'On';
      $(this).find('body').html('<br><br/>');
      this.contentWindow.focus(); //New
    }
  });

  $('#' + iframeDocumentId + '-container').append(iframe);


};

$('.rte-button-link').click(function() {
  var sText = iframeDocument.getSelection();
  var anchorTag = sText.anchorNode.parentNode;
  var url = $(anchorTag).prop('href');
  if (!url) {
    url = "https://";
  }
  var input = prompt("Please enter a url", url);
  if (input !== null) {
    iframeDocument.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a href="' + input + '" onclick="window.open(\'' + input + '\')" style="cursor: pointer;">' + sText + '</a>');
  }
});

$("#editor").createRichTextEditor(500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `anchorNode.parentNode`. This will return the HTML anchor node which you can use like this.

```
var sText = iframeDocument.getSelection();
var anchorTag = sText.anchorNode.parentNode;
console.log($(anchorTag).prop('href'));
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, it works! ANother problem is that when i use getSelection() it also grabs extra spaces and I cannot get the actual anchor tag. ANy idea how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you get then?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or show how are you selecting the content?

Comment: Added, but I don't know why the iframe is not editable here and cannot alert anything

Comment: _"I don't know why the iframe is not editable here and cannot alert anything"_ ==> That is probably because of a security restriction in SO which does not allow frames and there content to access the parent window (violating same origin policy).